# SFML Text appears gigantic in small View

Tags: c++, text, drawing, sfml

I've encountered a problem drawing SFML Text. In my application, I use views as a sort of coordinate system for my application. Thus, a typical view would be 10 x 10 or 20 x 20. All my normal drawing functions work fine, when drawing primitives and lines, etc., and the relevant code doesn't have to know about the coordinate system.

However, when I tried to draw text to the screen, I found that it appeared gigantic. When I reduced the font size drastically, it appeared extremely blurry and pixellated, as if it were trying to render to GIANT pixels that are 1x1 in my view.

Is there a way to draw text with a standard font size, in a way that it won't be affected by the view? Ideally, my text would width/size-wise on any view? How can I accomplish this?

Thanks for any input!

(P.S., I'm using SFML 2.0, for reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set another view (i.e. apply OpenGL transformation) and render text after it. Here is an example from [sfml tutorial](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/graphics-views.php):

```
sf::View View(sf::FloatRect(600, 700, 1400, 1300));
App.SetView(View);

// Draw the game...

App.SetView(App.GetDefaultView());

// Draw the interface...
```